# Explode rows with the same value PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql

What I wanted is to show the row of the same value. Here's the output:

[image]

here's the database:

[image]

As you can see on the image the table:25 should have 2 rows in 1 card based on the database.

here's the code:

```
$statement_select = $pdo_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders GROUP BY user_id");
$statement_select->execute();
$result = $statement_select->fetchAll();
 if ($result) {

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data_user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $data_ordered_product = $row['ordered_product'];
    $data_quantity = $row['quantity'];
    $data_size = $row['size'];
    $data_pickup_time = $row['pickup_time'];

   echo <<<EOD
<div class="cards">
    <div class=card_1>
        <div class="card_header">
            <p>TABLE: $data_user_id</p>
        </div>
        <div class=table_dashboard>
    <div class=table_row>
        <div class=column1>
                    <b>Item:</b>
        </div>
        <div class=column2>
                    <b>Qty:</b>
        </div>


        <div class=column1>
                    <p>$data_ordered_product($data_size)</p>

        </div>
        <div class=column2>
                    <p> $data_quantity</p>
        </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
 //disregard
    <div="table_footer">
        <p align="right"><b>Time:</b> $data_pickup_time &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

    <div class="group_options_1"><button>DONE</button></div>
    </div>
    </div>
 EOD;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your kind consideration :)

Comment: "the table:25 should have 2 rows based on the database". Should it? Please show us the raw data, then. As far as I can see your code already produces one HTML "card" for each row found in the Orders table. Are you saying the orders should all be inside one card? It's not very clear. Show us the source data and an example of the expected output.

Comment: on the user_id, there are 3 rows, and 2 rows that has the same value which are the Frappuccino and Espresso but only the Frappuccino was shown. On the other hand, the row must go on in the card if they have the same user_id

Comment: firstly I think you should change GROUP BY to ORDER BY in your query. Group by makes no sense in this situation. If you don't understand what it does, take a tutorial.

Comment: Secondly, in your loop you will need to track the user ID. If the user ID of the current row is the same as the user ID of the previous row then you need to not close off your card, but instead make a new entry in that card. Only when the user ID changes compared to the previous row do you start a new card. That's the logic, now see if you can implement it, it's not very hard to code once you know the algorithm. If you still get stuck, update your question with the latest version and explain the current problem.